# How to print matched filename only once for multiple matches (not printing only filenames)

Tags: shell-script, grep, logs

I'm grepping stuff from multiple logs at the same time with `grep -Er`

But I would like to have the matched file prefix only once.

What I want to achieve is kinda like `ls -lr` (matched file once followed by all matched lines per said file)

I have not found this option on the manual.

Am I able to achieve it with just grep ? How ?

Answer (score 1):

Not with any `grep` implementation that I know. `-r` itself is not a standard option. You could easily implement one in a script or function that uses `find` to find the files and `perl` to do the matching and report the file paths.

```
rPgrep() {
  local pattern="$1"
  shift
  find -- "$@" -type f -print0 |
    perl -C -0se '
      @ARGV = <STDIN>;
      $ /= "\n";
      while (<<>>) {
        if (/$pattern/) {
          unless ($header_already_printed) {
            print "\n" if defined $header_already_printed;
            print "$ARGV:\n";
            $header_already_printed = 1;
          }
          print;
        }
        $header_already_printed &&= 0 if eof;
      }' -- -pattern="$pattern"
}
```

And then:

```
rPgrep pattern some/dir some/other/dir or/regular/file
```

Replace `-type` with `-xtype` (assuming GNU `find`) if you want to also look into symlinks to regular files. Or add the `-L` option to `find` to also follow symlinks when descending the directory tree like GNU `grep -R` (as opposed to `-r`) does.

As a bonus, you get perl regexps (similar to the ones some `grep` support with `-P`) instead of the limited *extended* ones you get with `-E`.

Case insensitive matching (`-i`) or *word* matching (`-w`) or reverse matching (`-v`) or whole line matching (`-x`) can be done with regexp syntax (`(?i)`, `\b`, `(?!...)`, `^...\z`), but for the other `grep` options (`-n`, `-l`, `-F` or some non-standard extensions like `-o` / `-A` /`-B` / `-C`)..., the perl code would have to be modified.

You can also do things like:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -q pattern {} ';' \
               -exec printf '\n%s:\n' {} ';' \
               -exec grep pattern {} ';'
```

But that implies running up to three commands per file so is going to be quite inefficient.

With GNU `find`, the `-exec printf '\n%s:\n' {} ';'` can be replaced with `-printf '\n%p:\n'`.